# Split string base on the last N numbers of delimiters

Tags: c#

I need help to develop a logic to split a string, but only based on the last 2 delimiters of the string.

Example inputs:

```
string s1 = "Dog \ Cat \ Bird \ Cow";

string s2 = "Hello \ World \ How \ Are \ You";

string s3 = "I \ am \ Peter";
```

Expected Outputs:

```
string[] newS1 = "Dog Cat", "Bird", "Cow"
string[] newS2 = "Hello World How", "Are", "You"
string[] newS3 = "I", "am", "Peter"
```

So, as you can see, I only want to split the string on the last 2 "\", and everything else before the last 2 "\" will be concatenated into one string.

I tried the .Split method but it will just split every "\" in a string.

> Edited: If the string has less than 2 "\", it will just split according to whatever it has
>
> > Updates: Wow, these are a bunch of interesting solutions! Thank you a lot!

Comment: The removal of the "\" in the first element is intentional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var parts = s1.Split(new[] { " \\ " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var partsCount = parts.Count();
var result = new[] { string.Join(" ", parts.Take(partsCount - 2)) }.Concat(parts.Skip(partsCount - 2));
```

Comment: Yup, that's essentially what I suggested, just nicely codified.  The only caviat is according to 'spec' all separators are dropped, so the first param to join i think would be either space or empty string.

Comment: This results in an enumerable with `{ "Dog \ Cat ", " Bird ", " Cow" }`, instead of an array with `{ "Dog Cat", "Bird", "Cow" }` as was asked.

Comment: @Virtlink Thanks, edited! I'd probably accept your answer though since it's a little clearer what's going.

Comment: Yeah, I like to take the step-by-step approach, to show the OP how I came up with the code. It also ensures that each step is correct and compiles, something which your code currently doesn't (in my LINQPad). There's an error in your `Split`, there is no overload that takes only a string array. And the output is still not ideal: `{ "Dog___Cat ", " Bird ", " Cow" }`

Comment: Yea, coding from memory and forgot that overload required StringSplitOptions. To be fair, the OP's question doesn't compile either though, since they didn't escape the slashes!

Comment: @Virtlink Damnit! Thought I added those spaces too last edit!

Answer (score 5):

Offering a [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) solution:

```
var output = Regex.Split(input, @"\s*\\\s*([^\\]*?)\s*\\\s*(?=[^\\]*$)");
```

This split finds the second to last element and splits around that, but captures it in a group so it will be included in the output array.

For input `"Dog \ Cat \ Bird \ Cow"`, this will produce `{ "Dog \ Cat", "Bird", "Cow" }`. If you also need to strip the `\` out of the first element that can be done with a simple replace:

```
output[0] = output[0].Replace(" \\", "");
```

---

**Update**: This version will correctly handle strings with only one delimiter:

```
var output = Regex.Split(str, @"\s*\\\s*([^\\]*?)\s*\\\s*(?=[^\\]*$)|(?<=^[^\\\s]*)\s*\\\s*(?=[^\\\s]*$)");
```

---

**Update**: And to match other delimiters like whitespace, `"~"`, and `"%"`, you can use a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var output = Regex.Split(str, @"(?:[%~\s\\]+([^%~\s\\]+?)[%~\s\\]+|(?<=^[^%~\s\\]+)[%~\s\\]+)(?=[^%~\s\\]+$)");
```

The structure of this regex is slightly simpler than the previous one since it represents any sequence of one or more characters in the class `[%~\s\\]` as a delimiter, and any sequence of one or more characters in the negated character class `[^%~\s\\]` to be a segment. Note that the `\s` means ['whitespace' character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter).

You might also be able to simplify this further using:

```
var output = Regex.Split(str, @"(?:\W+(\w+)\W+|(?<=^\w+)\W+)(?=\w+$)");
```

Where `\w` matches any ['word' character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter) (letters, digits, or underscores) and `\W` matches any ['non-word' character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NonWordCharacter).

Comment: I really love this creative solution!

Comment: Regex always amazes me +1

Comment: @p.s.w.g can you please teach me how to modify your expression to match other delimiters? (I need an empty space, "~", as well as "%")

Comment: Wow, that's a well-explained answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) the string on every `<space>\<space>`:

```
string input = @"Dog \ Cat \ Bird \ Cow";
string[] parts = input.Split(new string[]{@" \ "}, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

And then [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) everything with a space in between, except the final two parts:

```
// NOTE: Check that there are at least 2 parts.
string part0 = String.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length - 2));
string part1 = parts[parts.Length - 2];
string part2 = parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

This will give you three strings, which you can put in an array.

```
string[] newParts = new []{ part0, part1, part2 };
```

In this example:

```
new [] { "Dog Cat", "Bird", "Cow" }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply taking the output of split, then taking first N-2 items and Join back together, then create new string array of 3 items, first being output of Join, second being item N-1 of first split, and third being N of first split.  I think that'll accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. My initial solution to this would be:

```
String[] tokens = theString.Split("\\");
String[] components = new String[3];
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 2; i++)
{
    components[0] += tokens[i];
}

components[1] = tokens[tokens.length - 2];
components[2] = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. But if it did, it would return `{ "Dog__Cat ", " Bird ", " Cow" }` instead of `{ "Dog Cat", "Bird", "Cow" }` as was asked.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I liked your answer by the way.

Comment: I would like your answer too if it compiled. I like to use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), and simply paste your code in there to see whether it compiles and what it produces.

Answer (score -1):

Loop from the end of the string and count delimiters until you encounter two.
Record index positions in 2 variables previously set to -1.

After the loop, if first var is -1, nothing happens, return whole string.

If second var is -1, create array of 2 strings, split using substring and return.

Create array of 3 string, split using information from two vars, return.

Hope you understood my pseudocode, give me a comment if you need help.

Comment: why downvote? this method is probably the fastest and most memory efficient here.

Comment: It's more suited to be a comment

Comment: But this is really an answer. It contains enough info to create a solution from it. Comments are used to ask for more information.